# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 error when using Android NDK C++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I'm getting the following error when making an Android app that uses both Java as well as C++ code through the NDK. Specifically, I've tried many valid inputs (this is a calculator app) and they all result in this error, but one, for example, that I tried was 4+3-5

```
05-03 00:54:05.676 30652-30652/com.x10host.dhanushpatel.nativecalc A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xd89f95b0 in tid 30652 (atel.nativecalc)
05-03 00:54:06.462 30652-30652/com.x10host.dhanushpatel.nativecalc W/atel.nativecalc: type=1701 audit(0.0:1454): auid=4294967295 uid=10192 gid=10192 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

I'm not sure what or where my error is or how to fix it.

This is my C++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <android/log.h>

using namespace std;
stack<string> operationsStack;
stack<double> numbersStack;
int arraySize = 0;

extern "C" {


void doOperation() {

    string oString = operationsStack.top();
    operationsStack.pop();

    double a = numbersStack.top();
    numbersStack.pop();
    double b = numbersStack.top();
    numbersStack.pop();

    if (oString == "x") {
        numbersStack.push(a * b);
    }
    else if (oString == "/") {
        numbersStack.push(b/a);
    }
    else if (oString == "+") {
        numbersStack.push(a + b);
    }
    else {
        numbersStack.push(b-a);
    }

}

double calcExpression(string calcArray[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        string chr = calcArray[i];
        if (chr == "(") {
        }
        else if (chr == "+" || chr == "x" || chr == "-" || chr == "/") {
            operationsStack.push(chr);
        }
        else if (chr == ")") {
            doOperation();
        }
        else {
            numbersStack.push(atof(chr.c_str()));
        }
    }
    doOperation();

    double result = numbersStack.top();
    numbersStack.pop();
    return result;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_x10host_dhanushpatel_nativecalc_MainActivity_calcPrint
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject jot, jobjectArray calcArray, jint aSize) {

    arraySize = aSize;

    string cppArray[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        jstring string = (jstring) ((env)->GetObjectArrayElement(calcArray, i));
        const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);
        cppArray[i] = rawString;
    }
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << calcExpression(cppArray);

    return env->NewStringUTF(oss.str().c_str());


}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_x10host_dhanushpatel_nativecalc_MainActivity_calcCClear(JNIEnv *env) {
    while (!operationsStack.empty()) {
        operationsStack.pop();
    }
    while (!numbersStack.empty()) {
        numbersStack.pop();
    }
}

}
```

This is my Java code:

```
package com.x10host.dhanushpatel.nativecalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private native String calcPrint(String[] jCL,int alLength);
    private native void calcCClear();
    ArrayList<String> jCalcList = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView calcShow;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("cplusplus11");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        calcShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calcShow);

    }

    public void calcAdd(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
        Log.i("button pressed: ",buttonText);
        jCalcList.add(buttonText);
        calcShow.setText(calcShow.getText().toString()+buttonText);
    }

    public void calcSum(View v){
        int jclSize = jCalcList.size();
        String[] jCalcArray = new String[jclSize];
        for(int i =0;i<jclSize;i++){
            jCalcArray[i]=jCalcList.get(i);
        }
        calcShow.setText(calcPrint(jCalcArray,jCalcArray.length));
    }

    public void calcClear(View v){
        calcCClear();
        calcShow.setText("");
    }

}
```

Help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `for(int i=0;i<calcArray->length();i++)`,  `calcArray->length()` is the length of the 1st string element of `calcArray` not the number of elements in `calcArray` itself.  Try changing `double calcExpression(string calcArray[])` to take a `std::vector<std::string>` rather than a C array.

Comment: You can also insert a special string at the end of your array when you are done modifying it. Then you can iterate through your array like `while calcArray[i] != "end"` to know the length

Comment: @Richard Critten and blackmesa, thanks for pointing those things out and giving advice! I modified my code so that the array size would be accessible everywhere, resolving my problem about that. I also had no return statement in doOperation earlier when it was of type double, but I realized it was supposed to be void, so I fixed that code too. I'm still getting the same error tho, but with a different fault addr and tid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've fixed my issue(s) and my code no longer gives any errors and my app no longer crashes. Effectively the code's logic is now working. Some features still need to be added/changed, but those things are irrelevant to the problems I mentioned here.

Edit: changes to my code that (probably) fixed it include properly setting/getting the max value of the loop in calcSum, using a double variable to store a double result instead of an int (somewhere in the C++ code), and there were probably other changes. Another thing I realized is my code was only evaluating expressions within parentheses, and that wasn't the program's fault, the fault lay with my assumptions about the code's logic.

Summary: if this error occurs in this sort of situation, you probably need to fix your code, the program is technically working as it should be according to your code.

Comment: @rmtheis I made multiple changes, my apologies for not adding details; I don't remember all of the specifics, but I added what I could now. I also updated the code in the post to reflect my changes/working code.